# jQuery Autocomplete in Wordpress

Tags: ajax, autocomplete

I'm using this autocomplete script https://github.com/agarzola/jQueryAutocompletePlugin within my wordpress theme. I have a form in a page where the user could specify some tags.
Actually, this is the code I'm using and it's working good.

```
    <script>
        jQuery(function() {
            var data = '<?php global $wpdb; $search_tags = $wpdb->
                   get_results("SELECT name FROM $wpdb->terms"); 
                      foreach ($search_tags as $mytag){ echo $mytag->name. " "; } ?>'.split(" ");
         $("#tags").autocomplete(data,{multiple: true});
            });
</script>
```

Now, the problem is,  this kind of query puts all the tags inside an array when I load the page. This could work if you have 100 tags, but we have a lot more. The script has also an autocomplete from remote script option as shown below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery().ready(function() {
    $("#tags").autocomplete("<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/get-tags.php", 
    {
        width: 260,
        matchContains: true,
        selectFirst: false,
        multiple: true
    });
});
</script>
```

This must activate autocomplete as the user types.
This is the code for get-tags.php (I put the file in my theme root)

```
<?php


include_once(‘../../../wp-config.php’);
include_once(‘../../../wp-load.php’);
include_once(‘../../../wp-includes/wp-db.php’);


global $wpdb; 
    $search_tags = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT name FROM $wpdb->terms"); 
        foreach ($search_tags as $mytag)
            { echo $mytag->name. " "; }


?>
```

I have tried everything and searched online for hours but I didn't find a solution on how to call the get-tags.php, it gives me an internal 500 error and the autocomplete doesn't work anymore.
thanks

Comment: You could turn this into an ajax request and have your ajax callback do the term fetching via admin-ajax.php, you'd then not need the extra file in your theme(with all those nasty looking includes).

Comment: @t31os How would you trigger the request for the autocomplete?

Comment: You ask me now after 11 months... lol... offhand, no idea, but i don't typically say something unless i think it's possible. Seeing as the asker got an answer he was happy with, i think i'll leave it at that... :) Valid point though.. (i'm terrible for drive-by comments)..

Comment: Yep, the answer worked for me. As I remember I had a little issue with the separator, but I found a workaround.

Comment: @t310s Guys, I'm asking because of [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/37202/ajax-and-autocomplete) Q. Yes, I'm not only here to _answer_ Qs ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

don't include WP like that. use `$_GET` instead:

```
...
$("#tags").autocomplete("<?php echo add_query_arg('get_my', 'terms', home_url()); ?>", 
...
```

theme's functions.php:

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'terms_for_autocomplete');
function terms_for_autocomplete(){
  if(isset($_GET['get_my']) && $_GET['get_my'] == 'terms'):

    $terms = &get_terms(get_taxonomies());
    foreach ($terms as $term)
      echo "{$term->name}|{$term->name} ({$term->count} results)\n";

    die();
  endif;
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's working. But as I type in the suggestion box I see all the tags together. Screenshot here http://img638.imageshack.us/img638/7216/screenshot20110108at102.png

Comment: well what kind of data does your autocomplete plugin expect? ...Try tags on each line: `echo $mytag->name. "\n";`

Comment: Great!! It's working. Now the problem is: 

- if I write a tag that exists and then I enter "," or "enter" it's ok. 

- If I try to write a new tag when I enter "," it put the first value of the database in the field.

I think the problem is how the Javascript handles the results.

Comment: I had a quick look at the plugin code, and it seems the results should be in a `value|title` format. so change them again to `echo  "{$mytag->name}|{$mytag->name}\n";` and see if that fixes your problem

Comment: It works but the problem is the same.

Comment: Just to let you know, I solved putting multipleSeparator: " " in the plugin options to avoid inserting comma to separate tags. I will force users to use dashes for multiple words as in stackoverflow (i.e. "web-development" "content-management"). Maybe with some Javascript I would solve my problem, but I'm not able to do it, so I managed to do in this way ;) thanks  again for your help!

Comment: Solved the comma problem: in jQuery autocomplete plugin include the option "selectFirst: false".

Comment: I've also updated my answer to use native WP functions without SQL