# Custom JSON feed rewrite

Tags: 404-error, permalinks, feed, json

I'm trying to implement a feed of information from an Event custom post type in JSON format, to be used in a FullCalendar implementation, pretty much as described [here](http://www.noeltock.com/web-design/wordpress/events-custom-post-types-fullcalendar-json-wordpress). The one thing I wanted to change was to create an actual WordPress feed to generate the JSON output, to avoid the hack of looking for wp-load.

This is the code: https://gist.github.com/1600619

I manage to get the valid output if I go to example.com?feed=json, but I think that the querystring is preventing FullCalendar from actually parsing it. I was hoping that having the feed with a proper URL like example.com/feed/json would fix it, but that gets me just a 404.

Comment: Is it essential that its a feed? I have used this in a plug-in I've developed, except I populated the events by using WordPress' in-built method of handling Ajax requests ([see this question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/37202/ajax-and-autocomplete/37322#37322)). This removes the necessity of hunting down for the wp-load.php.

Comment: That would actually be perfect; is it possible to update the calendar whenever the view is changed that way, I suppose?

Answer (score 3):

The AJAX request would query for the dates it requires to display. With Lazy fetching set, if you switch from month to week or day views it won't bother making another request, since it doesn't need to. This is outlined in the fullcalendar [documentation](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/lazyFetching/).

As for using this method, [see this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/37202/ajax-and-autocomplete/37322#37322) on how to obtain the admin-ajax.php url properly.

Next, you need to set the fullcalendar source appropriately and then define the ajax action. The following is taken from my [`Event Organiser`](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/event-organiser/) plugin. So feel free to nose around to get the details (you'll want `frontend.js` in the js folder and `event-organiser-ajax.php` in the includes folder).

**The Event source**

```
jQuery(".eo-fullcalendar").fullCalendar({
    lazyFetching: 'true',
    events:  function(start, end, callback) {
        jQuery.ajax({
               url: MYAJAX.url+"?action=mycalendaraction",
           dataType: 'JSON',
               data: {
                 start: jQuery.fullCalendar.formatDate(start, 'yyyy-MM-dd'),
                 end:jQuery.fullCalendar.formatDate(end, 'yyyy-MM-dd')
                },
                success: function(data) {
                  callback(data);
                 }
              })
       }
 });
```

By default the start and end dates are as timestamps, but my query required it in YYYY-MM-DD format. The `MYAJAX.url` is the admin-ajax.php url which you set, as explained in the linked question, by using `wp_localize_script`.

Finally, you need to add the appropriate actions to deal with the request:

```
 if ( isset( $_REQUEST['action'] ) AND 'mycalendaraction' === $_REQUEST['action'] ) {
        //For logged in users. 
         do_action( "wp_ajax_{$_REQUEST['action']}" );
        // For non-logged in users: 
         do_action( "wp_ajax_nopriv_{$_REQUEST['action']}" );
    }

add_action( 'wp_ajax_mycalendaraction', 'get_my_events' ); 
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_mycalendaraction', 'get_my_events' ); 
    function get_my_events() {
        //$_GET['start'] the start date
        //$_GET['end'] the end date
        //perform query
        //Let $events_array be the array of events with each event being an appropriate array (for instance with 'title','start','end','allDay' keys - see fullcalendar documentation). 
        //Echo result and exit
        echo json_encode($event_sarray);
        exit;
}
```

In the above I am assuming the calendar is for both logged-in and non-logged-in users (hence both actions). You way also want to perform some nonce checks (see the linked question). Note the action is the same as that set in the ajax url of the 'Event source' section.

What should be included in each event array is given in the fullcalendar documentation under 'Event Object'. On the javascript side an associative array (i.e. an event) is recieved as an object with values given by the values in the array: I.e. `event['key']` becomes `event.key`

*Disclaimer: The above code has been changed to make things clearer and so has not been tested.*

Comment: I had problems with the following line: ´jQuery.fullcalendar.formatDate´ so i used this instead: ´start.toISOString()´