# What is the "proper" way to generate a javascript variable depending on a custom field value?

Tags: javascript, headers

On my site I have some posts with a custom field "Name". Now, in case the post has "Name" set, I want to generate this code:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var FG_DONATE_BUTTON_PARAMS = { attribution: 'honor',   attribution_name: Name}     
</script>
```

where Name after attribution_name refers to the custom field value. For test purpose, I've used this code in the header

```
$nameAttribute= get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Name', true); 
printf('<script type=\'text/javascript\'>
var FG_DONATE_BUTTON_PARAMS = { 
    attribution: \'honor\', 
    attribution_name: \'' . $nameAttribute .'\'
} </script>');
```

But I have two problems. One, the value of the $nameAttribute doesn't get passed through, and secondly, it's ugly :) I think I can manage the value problem, but I'm unsure what would be the "proper" way to output this.

Comment: Don't print <script> into the page, use `wp_enqueue_script` and `wp_localize_script` instead. As shown explained: http://ottopress.com/2010/passing-parameters-from-php-to-javascripts-in-plugins/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may wish to look at [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/37202/ajax-and-autocomplete/37322#37322). In that question, the admin-ajax url is passed through, but it can be any variable (or array of variables), like for instance `$nameAttribute`.

For instance, you would call

```
wp_localize_script('my_js_file_handle','my_js_object',array('attribute'=>$nameAttribute))`
```

then in your js file, the variable would be accessible from my_js_object.attribute.

(You must enqueue the javascript file though!)