# Not sure why wp_ajax isn't working?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to get into grips in using AJAX in wordpress, the following code creates a form with an input box using the wordpress feature shortcode [ajaxf].

```
<?php
add_action( "wp_ajax_ajaxcf", "my_action_callback" );
add_action( "wp_ajax_nopriv_ajaxcf", "my_action_callback" );

function my_action_callback() {
    $whatever = intval( $_POST['fname'] );
    echo $whatever;
    die(); 
}
function ajax_contact_form() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript" >
jQuery(".submit").click(function() {
    jQuery.post(ajaxurl, $('#ajaxForms').serialize(), function(response) {
        alert('Got this from the server: ' + response);
    });
}); 
</script>

<form id="ajaxForms">   
    <label for="fname">First Name:</label>
    <input id="fname" name="fname" value="First Name" type="text" />
  </p>

  <p class="submit">
    <input name="action" type="hidden" value="ajaxcf" />
    <input id="submit_button" class="submit" value="Send" type="button" />
  </p>
</form>
<?php
    }
add_shortcode("ajaxcf", "ajax_contact_form");
```

I simply want to alert the response with jQuery but it doesn't seem to work and i have no idea why.

Help appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a simple javascript issue. When your javascript that attaches the click behavior to the form is parsed, the form element doesn't yet exist because it's further down the page, so it doesn't get attached. Either move the javascript below the form, wrap it in a `jQuery(document).ready()`, or use [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/).

EDIT - `$('#ajaxForms').serialize();` should be `jQuery('#ajaxForms').serialize();`, you need to define `ajaxurl` in your javascript: `var ajaxurl = "<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>";`, otherwise your code works fine, tested here.

Comment: Hi Milo, I have moved the jQuery further down the page and even wrapped it around a jQuery document ready and the code still doesn't work, it wouldn't surprise me if there is an error within the jQuery. Matt

Comment: @MattStrange - see edit above.

Comment: Thanks man, works! One thing i don't understand is in the wordpress codex it says the admin-ajax.php is already included..

Answer (score 0):

This [question here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/37202/ajax-and-autocomplete/37322#37322) might help you.

Basically, you need to make sure you specify an 'action' when you post you ajax request. In your code the action is 'ajaxcf'.

In your plugin/ theme's functions.php file you then need hook onto `init` a function that checks the action, checks any nonces if necessary and then calls the following;

```
 do_action( "wp_ajax_ajaxcf" );
 do_action( "wp_ajax_nopriv_ajaxcf" );
```

---

**EDIT** 
I've not checked the JavaScript side of things, see Milo's response. But `wp_ajax_ajaxcf` is not a default action, so you have to 'do' it.

Comment: Thanks Stephen for the reply, i have specified the action in the html form..  `<input name="action" type="hidden" value="ajaxcf" />`

Comment: Apologies, I missed that. See my comment on 'do_action' :D

Comment: Kk, i'm working from the tutorial found on the wordpress codex, i'm not sure if the do_action is necessary... ?? http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Comment: Hi, Matt - you're right, my mistake!