# Link permalink in Twitter Bootstrap "TypeAhead" results

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Twitter Bootstrap have a javascript plugin called [TypeAhead](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#typeahead) which is simular to Google Instant Search. I'm using it to pull the WordPress post titles into the search box, using the following code c/o @StephenHarris

```
data-source='[<?php 
    $posts = get_posts( array( 'numberposts' => -1, 'category' => 0 ) );
    $post_titles = wp_list_pluck( $posts, 'post_title' ); 
    $post_titles = array_map( 'esc_html', $post_titles ); 
    echo '"'.implode( '","', $post_titles ).'"';
?>]'
```

But how would you link the post permalink to the drop-down list of post titles?

Comment: I wouldn't use that, looks very inefficient. What happens when you get to ~1K posts? :) There are many autocomplete plugins out there which perform better

Comment: It's for a website that will only ever have a maximum of 100/150 posts. But I will look for some plugins options.

Comment: ----deleted----

Comment: There is actually an excellent Wordpress plugin that provides autocomplete that is much smarter than just searching the titles: [Swiftype Search](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/swiftype-search/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As **@OneTrickPoney** points out, there's an alternative in core.

[jQuery UI autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) comes with WP default install.

> Autocomplete, when added to an input field, enables users to quickly find and select from a pre-populated list of values as they type, leveraging searching and filtering.
>   By giving an Autocomplete field focus or entering something into it, the plugin starts searching for entries that match and displays a list of values to choose from. By entering more characters, the user can filter down the list to better matches.
>
> This can be used to enter previous selected values, for example you could use Autocomplete for entering tags, to complete an address, you could enter a city name and get the zip code, or maybe enter email addresses from an address book.
>
> You can pull data in from a local and/or a remote source: Local is good for small data sets (like an address book with 50 entries), remote is necessary for big data sets, like a database with hundreds or millions of entries to select from.
>
> Autocomplete can be customized to work with various data sources, by just specifying the source option.

<sup>Explanation @jQuery</sup>

Just enqueue and go. [Take a look at my Q](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/37202/ajax-and-autocomplete), where you'll find some basics about it.