# wpquery via ajax

Tags: wp-query, ajax

I can reload my page and have php write a new **wpquery** and replace the content on my page, but I really don't want to deal with a new page load. Is there an *easy* way to send a **wpquery** string (eg `"p=7"`) via **ajax**? Even if I have to make a custom php page to query, that's fine.

I'm still new to wordpress so I wanted to make sure there's no easy way to do this before I start taking the "scenic" route. **Thanks.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The accepted answer on this post:

[Ajax and autocomplete](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/37202/ajax-and-autocomplete)

does an extremely good job of showing exactly how to integrate an ajax call within Wordpress.