# Custom post content to display in a normal post?

Tags: custom-post-types

Is it possible to display custom post content in a normal Wordpress post?

For example I have created a custom post type called Games Database, it is populated with game boxart, title, genre, platform, publisher, developer, review score and release date.  Now when I create a new (normal) wordpress post I want to be able to select a game from a drop down menu that the post relates to, for instance if I'm writing a post about Mario Galaxy 2 I would want to select that game from my database and then when I view the post on the website I want to be able to see a widget display with all of the games details.

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution #1 - home brew

You could

- add a metabox using [`add_meta_box()` <sup>Example on the bottom of that link</sup>](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box).
- In your MetaBox callback you could add a Query [like this one](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/71343/creating-a-front-end-based-user-search/71346#71346), but for posts
- Then use the jQuery UI Autocomplete plugin that is shipped with WordPress like [explained in that answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/37202/ajax-and-autocomplete).

#### Solution #2 - from the super market

But you could as well use "Posts2Posts" which can be found

- [in the official repo](http://wordpress.org/plugins/posts-to-posts/) on wp.org
- [or on GitHub](https://github.com/scribu/wp-posts-to-posts/) where you'll find extensive tutorials in the Wiki and help in the questions/issues list.

Comment: You have certainly given for some food for thought there @Kaiser, I'm going to try and do a little more research before attempting it as I'm a novice at PHP lol, cheers!